# Constructor overloading for two types

Tags: c++, c++11

I am making a class `User`. I have done some constructor overloading below:

```
class User
{
    public:
    explicit User(string firstInit, string secondInit){
        this->firstInit = firstInit;
        this->secondInit = secondInit;    
    }//end constructor

    explicit User(char firstInit, char secondInit){
        this->firstInit = firstInit;
        this->secondInit = secondInit;    
    }//end constructor

    explicit User(string firstInit, char secondInit){
        this->firstInit = firstInit;
        this->secondInit = secondInit;    
    }//end constructor    

    explicit User(char firstInit, string secondInit){
        this->firstInit = firstInit;
        this->secondInit = secondInit;    
    }//end constructor        
};
```

My question relates to constructor overloading. Do I need to provide all 4 examples of a constructor in this case to meet the requirement that:

> An initial can be a string or character. It does not matter. But account for all cases where a user may enter one or the other.

For "best practice", did I satisfy the requirement? Or is there a way to declare an `enum` with only `string` and `char` and each variable must be one of those `enum`?

Comment: "Best practice" is always initializing class members in the constructor's initialization list, and not in the constructor body. "`this->somethingorother`" in the constructor is never "best practice". As far as the rest of the question, it's too vague and too broad to be able to give a definitive answer.

Comment: _"where a user may enter one or the other."_ Doesn't this require only two constructors? One for string and one for char? Maybe that's just my interpretation.

Comment: Unless you are willing to create a separate string-like class, which will be convertible from `char` and `const char[2]`, then it's as good as it can be.

Comment: Hi @SamVarshavchik, sorry for the delayed response. Could you post an example of what you mean as an answer? I'm sort of self-teaching myself C++ so outside of this textbook and Stack Overflow I don't have a lot of experience.

Comment: @churill Not quite; there are two variables which must be passed to the constructor, and the two variables can be either a string or a char. Sorry for bad wording.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen that sounds interesting, but might be above my level of expertise. If you are willing to post an example, that might be the better solution.

Comment: Your aforementioned C++ textbook should have plenty of examples of using constructor initialization lists. Stackoverflow is not really a substitute for a good C++ book. And, I already mentioned that this is too vague and too broad to have a definitive answer. Only you know the exact details of your class and how it should work, and proper construction/initialization depends on the details of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have either a single `char` or whole `std::string`. Since `std::string` can also be used to hold a single `char`, I suggest to use the following:

```
class User
{
private:
    std::string first;
    std::string second;

public:
    explicit User(std::string firstInit, std::string secondInit) :
        first(firstInit),
        second(secondInit)
    {
        //Only this constructor actually initializes any variables.
    }

    explicit User(char firstInit, char secondInit) : User(std::string({ firstInit }), std::string({ secondInit }))
    {
    }

    explicit User(std::string firstInit, char secondInit) : User(firstInit, std::string({ secondInit }))
    {
    }

    explicit User(char firstInit, std::string secondInit) : User(std::string({ firstInit }), secondInit)
    {
    }
};
```

This also uses constructor delegation in case you need a more complex initialization logic, which you don't want to repeat all over.

As explanation: `std::string({ firstInit })` will create `std::string` with one char.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an overkill for this particular case, but you could also roll out a separate class, which is constructible from both `char`, `const char*` (a string literal) and possibly `std::string`.

```
class SingleChar 
{
public:
    SingleChar(char c): c{c} {} //constructors are implicit by design
    SingleChar(const char* c): c{c[0]} {}
    char asChar() {return c;}
    std::string asString() {return std::string(1, c);}
private:
    char c;
};
```

With such a class, your constructor can accept both `'a'` and `"a"` as valid entry:

```
class User
{
    User(SingleChar firstInit, SingleChar secondInit):
        firstInit{firstInit.asChar()}, //or asString if you'd rather have std::string
        secondInit{secondInit.asChar()}
    {}
private:
    char firstInit;
    char secondInit;
};

User x {'a', "a"}; //works
```

But as I said, this might be an overkill. Also, it may be argueable which version is easier to read - `char` and `std::string` are obvious and everyone knows them, but `SingleChar` is something new and reader has to first understand what does this class do.